# How to restrict user to turn on Audio and Video in Jitsi conference call?

Tags: android, android-studio, video-conferencing, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I want to restrict certain user to turn on Audio and Video option in Jitsi meet activity. I am able to mute Audio and Video but user can turn them on back. I want to completely restrict them to turn them on.

Here is code snippet I have,

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions defaultOptions
                        = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                        .setServerURL(new URL(APIClass.JITSI_SERVER_URL))
                        .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                        .setAudioOnly(true)
                        .build();

JitsiMeet.setDefaultConferenceOptions(defaultOptions);
```

I found couple of methods but it is not useful as per the requirments,

[image: JistiMeetConferenceOptions]

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's late, but at least I have a suggestion.
You have the possibility to set feature flags, where you can disable chat, calendar, and so on.

So I would do it like:

```
JitsiMeetConferenceOptions defaultOptions = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
            .setServerURL("your.server.url)
            .setToken(authToken)
            .setFeatureFlag("recording.enabled", false)
            .setFeatureFlag("chat.enabled", false)
            .setFeatureFlag("add-people.enabled", false)
            .setFeatureFlag("share.enabled", false) 
            // look for more feature flags
            .build();
```

I don't know the class anymore where the flags are defined, but you can find them in the sdk.

Hope it helps.